# How do you center a rectangle in javaScript? Having the X and Y position of the rectangle being the center of the rectangle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How do you center a rectangle in javaScript?  Having the X and Y position of the rectangle being the center of the rectangle. This is a rough idea for my code.

```
var cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvas = var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

function createSprite(x,y,width,height) {
 this.x=x;
 this.y=y;
 this.width=width;
 this.height=height;

 this.display(){
 
 cxt.beginPath();
 cxt.rect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
 cxt.fill();
 cxt.stroke();
 
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unconventional, but simple if you really want to do it that way:

```
var cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvas = var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

function createSprite(x,y,width,height) {
 this.x=x;
 this.y=y;
 this.width=width;
 this.height=height;

 this.display(){
 
 cxt.beginPath();
 cxt.rect(this.x - this.width / 2, this.y - this.height / 2,this.width,this.height);
 cxt.fill();
 cxt.stroke();
 
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank for the solution, I had a very hard time coming up with a answer and this did the trick.

Comment: You're welcome - please mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to Stack Overflow how do I mark as answer? Edit: never mind I figured it out